# Vertically aligning suffix with tab space in android TextView

Tags: android, textview, vertical-alignment

I have rows (of horizontal `LinearLayout`) with a `TextView` at the end that displays time. An this is how it looks:

[image]

Now I need the suffix (am/pm) in all rows to be aligned vertically. This is not the case in the above layout, as you can see, the last row is misaligned as the displayed time is longer.

I achieved this using the tab character \u0009. This means I would set the text to be for example "7:21\u0009\u0009pm". This produces desired result as show below:

[image]

However, I need to know if **(1) this is the most efficient way** and **(2) that this would work on all android devices**. If there is an alternative way to achieve this please let me know.

And here is an XML layout of a row for your reference:

```
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/prayer_time_row_height"
            android:layout_marginLeft="48dp"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <com.devspark.robototextview.widget.RobotoTextView
                style="@style/text_subhead"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="Today"
                android:textColor="@color/material_light_secondary_text"
                android:visibility="invisible" />

            <com.devspark.robototextview.widget.RobotoTextView
                style="@style/text_subhead"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="Event"
                android:textColor="@color/material_light_primary_text" />

            <com.devspark.robototextview.widget.RobotoTextView
                style="@style/text_subhead"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="12:06\u0009\u0009am"
                android:textColor="@color/material_light_primary_text" />

        </LinearLayout>
```

**BONUS**

Bonus points for pointing out a way to vertically align the hour-minute separator, i.e., colon character.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe using tabs **is** the most efficient, but the gap is pretty big and not configurable. If you need all those rows in a single view group, you may try to check out RelativeLayout: align am/pm vertically on common left, and put hours to the left and on the baseline. This is the most flexible way, since you can control relative positions and margins, but computation-wise it's less efficient because it requires extra calculation upon laying out elements.

As per aligning colons — in most fonts (not just monospace) digits are designed to take equal space, so just align the numbers on the right (e.g. in relative layout) and it should do.

Comment: P.S. If you need these entries separately (e.g. in a ListView), then the best way would probably be placing the numbers and am/pm label separately in a horizontal LinearLayout, both layout_width=0 and layout_weight`s of your choice — this way each of the columns will have fixed width across all rows

Answer (score 2):

For the colon character, you could try using the character "\uee01" instead of ":". This is what google does with the clock in the lock screen.

https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/packages/Keyguard/src/com/android/keyguard/KeyguardStatusView.java#L247

Answer (score 1):

You can use a 2-column TableLayout.  The first column is the time without AM/PM and the second column is just the AM/PM.  Set the gravity of the first column to "end" or "right" and the times will be lined up at the colons if you are using a fixed width font.